# SQLCLR Impersonation keeps using the service identity

Tags: sql-server, impersonation, account, sqlclr

I have the following code:

```
Public Shared Function MyTest() As SqlString

    Dim rc As String = Nothing
    Dim impersonatedUser As WindowsImpersonationContext = Nothing
    If SqlContext.IsAvailable Then
        If SqlContext.WindowsIdentity IsNot Nothing Then
            impersonatedUser = SqlContext.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate
        End If
    End If
    Try
        rc = System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Data Files\Test\42.txt").ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    Finally
        If impersonatedUser IsNot Nothing Then
            impersonatedUser.Undo()
        End If
    End Try

    Return rc
End Function
```

In SQL the declation of the assembly is as follows:

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY aKeyCLR FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = '$(BASE)CLR.dll'
CREATE LOGIN CLRLogin FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY aKeyCLR
GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO CLRLogin
```

The create function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Test()
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
AS
    EXTERNAL NAME myStuff.[CLR.FileFunctions].[MyTest]
GO
```

When I execute `SELECT Test()` the file access is still done by account "NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER". I am logged on to SQL server with Windows Authentication and would expect that user to do the file access.

What am I missing here?

Comment: That does look correct. Can you either debug and set a break-point within the `If SqlContext.WindowsIdentity IsNot Nothing Then` condition, else add a line that will do something in there that will clearly indicate that the branch has been entered. Also, why do you think that the security context is still `NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER` and not your Windows Login?

Comment: I am 100% sure it gets in the inner IF, I proved it by setting a fixed return value there. I used System Internals ProcMon to see which user is accessing the folder.

Comment: Hmm. You might want to test by allowing read access only to your Windows Login and then changing the `Exists()` into `string _Test = ReadAllText()` or something like that.

Comment: I did what you proposed; Removed all ntfs rights for the service account and to my big surprise the function kept working. The CreateFile event in ProcMon now shows my Windows login as impersonating account so it seems to work as designed. Thanks for you're help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to be correct. You can test by allowing read access only to your Windows Login and then changing the `Exists()` into `string _Test = ReadAllText()` or something like that.

What you are initially seeing is the main identity of the process. Impersonating another account is not a replacement of the original security context, it is simply a new SID (Security ID) to run the process as. In fact, impersonating an OS account does not change the "active" User in the Registry (i.e. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`), nor does it reset the environment variables (i.e. `PATH`, `TEMP`, etc); those actions happen upon a full login.

Within SQL Server, when impersonating via `EXECUTE AS`, you can see the main identity of the Session via the `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

By clicking one step further into ProcMon on the CreateFile event, the event properties reveal the impersonating user.

Working as designed!